# Code igniter htaccess pointing to a folder while removing index.php and adding www

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

As the title says, I am using Code Igniter, need to point to a folder on godaddy hosting account, while removing index.php and adding www.

My current settings work for the main page only, also all the css and js files get included. However, none of the internal links work and i get 500 internal server error.

all the current settings:

- In the domain settings, it is pointing to a folder on my hosting, working correctly since the main site loads.
- config.php

  > $config['base_url']    = 'http://www.example.com';
  >
  > $config['index_page'] = '';
- htaccess file

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
> ```

Edit:  Managed to solve it, all that was missing was this line

> RewriteBase /

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure whether it will work for you or not but i am using it and its working fine for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

just paste the code in your root directory .htaccess file. Please let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, i tryed it, this or my htaccess works, but not when i am pointing the domain to a folder. Only the main page loads fine while al the internal links give a 500 internal server error